# Is there a way to see UI updates while debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, user-interface

At the moment I'm trying to debug some code in which I'm cheking for the visibility of items (with the `.IsVisible()` method for example). The problem is, when I'm jumping from one breakpoint to the next or jumping between lines, the data obviously changes, but the UI of the program doesn't seem to change at all. That makes it a bit difficult for me to tell if things are visible and I have to trust Visual Studio.

Is there a way I can make the UI update while debugging, so I can see the changes over there as well?

Comment: Are you using the PropertyChanged-Event? Else you can change your data and it won't change in the UI, cause the value there is only set in the InitializeComponents()-Method, unless you use that event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to force a synchronous re-render of the UI. You could define this extension method somewhere:

```cs
public static void SynchronouslyRedraw(this UIElement uiElement) {
    uiElement.InvalidateVisual();
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() => { })).Wait();
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => { })).Wait();
}
```

and call it on your `Window` after each breakpoint (using the immediate window, a breakpoint action, an additional line of code etc). It should synchronously re-render the `Window` in question:

```cs
this.SynchronouslyRedraw(); // assuming your breakpoint is in your `Window` class for example.
```

Note that this method works on any `UIElement` that is in the visual tree of a `Window` object.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Thanks, this is getting me closer to solving my refresh problem, where despite PropertyChanged firing the UI does not update.

Answer (score 0):

The UI only updates when you give it a chance - that means not occupying the UI thread with other work (such as your event handler).

There isn't a simple way to do this in the debugger in WPF. In Windows Forms, you can just use `Application.DoEvents();`, but WPF requires you to `await Dispatcher.Yield();`, so you can't just execute it whenever you want. Both solve the same problem in much the same way - they give the message loop an opportunity to handle all the pending messages, and then go back to where you left off. Both also have the same weakness - they introduce an opportunity for reentrancy, so be careful.